# Can I use both dir and buildFile in a GradleBuild task?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to call a gradle task from a sub directory, using a different builg.gradle file.
I have the following task:

```
task(subTask, type: GradleBuild) {
    dir = new File(project.projectDir, "db/" + project.dbName)
    buildFile = new File(project.projectDir, "build.gradle.subdir")
    tasks = [params,...]
    startParameter.projectProperties = [env: project.env]
}
```

I can either pass 'dir' or 'buildFile', but when I pass both, then the projectDir will be the directory where the passed 'buildFile' resides and not the one I pass as 'dir', and I would like them to be in 2 different directories, as seen in the above task. Any idea how could this be done?

update:
so I have the following files:

build.gradle
build.gradle.subdir
db/dbA/
db/dbA/gradle.properties
db/dbB/
db/dbB/gradle.properties

because of some historic things currently we do the following:
cp build.gradle.subdir db/dbA/build.gradle
cd db/dbA
../gradlew task...

and I need to do it for each sub-directory under db

So I thought I might do at least 1 step further (although still hacky) and eliminate the need of an external shell script to do the loop over the directories, and the copy, cd.

I am almost there:
I am able to manually copy the build.gradle.subdir and then the above task (without passing buildFile) works
OR
I can pass buildFile, but not the dir, in which case it starts to run the task, but it doesn't read db/dirA/gradle.properties, which is needed to do the task.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? The project directory is always the directory containing the build script. This cannot be changed.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project directory must be the same directory as the directory containing the build script and `gradle.properties` file. You'll have to find a different solution to your problem.